# Run a Change Role Cron Job on WordPress via cPanel

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

Can someone point me in the right direction here?

I'm attempting to set up a plugin that sets up a cron job on activation to change the user_role of a user after 3 months of their user_registered date. The cron job should be removed when the plugin is deactivated as well.

**The plugin code so far is:**

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Cron Job
*/

add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'example_add_cron_interval' );

function example_add_cron_interval( $schedules ) {
    $schedules['five_seconds'] = array(
        'interval' => 5,
        'display'  => esc_html__( 'Every Five Seconds' ),
    );

    return $schedules;
}

function cron_hook(){
    $users = get_users(
        array(
            'fields' => array( 'ID', 'user_registered' ),
            'role'   => 'coaching',
        )
    );

    foreach ( $users as $user ) {

        $time = $user->user_registered;

        if(strtotime($time) < strtotime('-3 months')) {
            $u = new WP_User( $user->ID );
            // Remove role
            print_r($u);

            $u->remove_role( 'coaching' );

            // Add role
            $u->add_role( 'platinum' );
        }
    }
}

//echo '<pre>'; print_r( _get_cron_array() ); echo '</pre>';

public static function activate() {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'five_seconds', 'cron_job' );
}

public static function deactivate() {
    wp_clear_scheduled_hook('cron_job');
}
```

I'm running wp-cron.php through cPanel (currently set to five_seconds for testing).

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find the solution.

My finished code is:

```
register_activation_hook ( __FILE__, 'cron_job' );

function cron_job() 
{
wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'hourly_job' );
}

add_action( 'hourly_job', 'cron_job_task' );

function cron_job_task () 
{
    $users = get_users(
        array(
            'fields' => array( 'ID', 'user_registered' ),
            'role'   => 'coaching',
        )
    );

    foreach ( $users as $user ) {
        $time = $user->user_registered;
        if(strtotime($time) < strtotime('-3 months')) {
            $u = new WP_User( $user->ID );
            $u->remove_role( 'coaching' );
            $u->add_role( 'platinum' );
        }
    }
}
?>
```

With a cPanel cron job set hourly.